# In Ubuntu, routes are not added as defined in rc.local file....why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ip, alias

I need to setup my ubuntu pc single nic card ip as 192.168.1.6 for internet and 10.172.170.95 and 135.10.86.100 for my lan and for another network through my 4port DSL modem.So i defined like this.

Except addition of last two routes(10.0.0.0/8 & 200.200.176.0/24) everything worked as defined, what is the mistake i did?

In /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

In /etc/rc.local file

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 135.10.86.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
/sbin/ifconfig eth0:1 10.172.170.95 netmask 255.0.0.0.0
ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 10.172.170.6 src 10.172.170.95
ip route add 200.200.176.0/24 via 135.10.86.176 src 135.10.86.100
```

after restart,
i found

ifconfig output as,

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:82:87:12:4b  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:85ff:fe96:441b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:417620 (417.6 KB)  TX bytes:93772 (93.7 KB)
          Interrupt:26 Base address:0xa000 

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:82:87:12:4b  
          inet addr:135.10.86.100  Bcast:135.10.86.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:26 Base address:0xa000 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:82:87:12:4b  
          inet addr:10.172.170.95  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:26 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 B)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 B)
```

and route -n as,

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
135.10.86.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

rc.local is not the best place to set up additional NIC aliases and routes.

Just use /etc/network/interfaces for that.

[NIC alias example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-or-adding-new-network-alias-to-a-network-card-nic/)

[static routes example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configuring-static-routes-in-debian-or-red-hat-linux-systems.html)

Concerning your problem:

you use an absolute path to the ifconfig tool, but a relative path to the ip tool. Try using an absolute path there too. Find it by using `which ip` or `whereis ip`.